# Capacitors bridging over transformer in insulated power supply

Tags: power-supply, power, circuit-analysis

I need an **isolated power supply** for powering a device that’s very sensitive to current leak (see below). I bought [one such isolated power supply](https://aliexpress.com/item/32824183162.html) from Aliexpress. What surprised me is that there seem to be two capacitors bridging the isolating transformer.

[image: Top view]
[image: Bottom view]
[image: Detail]

I wonder if these two components somewhat undermine the “isolation properties” and if I should perhaps remove them? What are they there for anyway?

BTW the black rectangular component adjacent to the top side capacitor on the first photo is an *optocoupler* so that should be ok.

FYI the sensitive device is an [Atlas Scientific pH probe](https://www.atlas-scientific.com/product_pages/circuits/ezo_ph.html) measuring my pool pH connected to a Raspberry Pi. Apparently the current leak between the mains switching 5V powersupply and the pool water is enough to completely throw off the measurements. When the RPi is powered from a battery power bank it gives accurate results.

Can / should I remove the two blue things?

Comment: First you might try to earth the negative output of the power supply so to divert leakage current from the pool. Removing the capacitors could not be a good idea, they are supposed to locally close high frequency noise current.

Comment: See my answer here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/478607/feeling-a-tingling-sensation-by-touching-stuff-is-this-safe/478626#478626 And here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/388155/strange-thing-with-5mm-leds-and-variable-psu/388157#388157

Comment: @Andyaka Thanks, your links seem to confirm that there may be a current leak through these capacitors. What if I remove them? Will that harm the RPi?

Comment: It could harm the RPi.

Comment: @carloc: Voluntary earthing a SELV circuit is in most cases not permitted because it violates regulations.

Comment: The dual caps will shunt primary switching differential noise by the low impedance secondary DC yet create a larger common mode noise. but consider your signal is < 200mV < 15Hz , how much voltage you expect from say 200uA at 25kHz.